# After Specific Value Occurs N Times, Replace All Remaining Occurrences with Different Value

Tags: r, for-loop

Here is my data set:

```
VarID    x1      x2      x3     x4     x5
1        Red     Yellow  Green  Green  Green 
2        Yellow  Green   Green  Green  Green 
3        Red     Red     Red    Yellow Green
```

I'm looking to write a for loop that goes through each row and after a specific value, in this case the word "Green," appears n times, I want to replace all remaining "Green" values with something else. I want to replace all remaining values of "Green" with the word "Go" after the word "Green" has appeared 2 times. The output should look like this:

```
VarID    x1      x2      x3     x4     x5
1        Red     Yellow  Green  Green  Go
2        Yellow  Green   Green  Go     Go
3        Red     Red     Red    Yellow Green
```

I imagine a for loop would do the trick unless a function would be more efficient? This is what I tried but I know there is an issue with the syntax so I'm not sure how to code it.

```
for(x in data){
   if(sum(which(data=="Green"))>2){
       data[x=="Green, ] <- "Go"
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, try this:

```
addGo <- function(x) replace(x, cumsum(x == "Green") > 2 & x == "Green", "Go")
replace(DF, -1, replace(DF[-1], TRUE, t(apply(DF[-1], 1, addGo))))
```

giving:

```
  VarID     x1     x2    x3     x4    x5
1     1    Red Yellow Green  Green    Go
2     2 Yellow  Green Green     Go    Go
3     3    Red    Red   Red Yellow Green
```

or write it like this:

```
isGreen <- DF[-1] == "Green"
replace(DF, -1, replace(DF[-1], t(apply(isGreen, 1, cumsum)) > 2 & isGreen, "Go"))
```

### Note

The input is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
VarID    x1      x2      x3     x4     x5
1        Red     Yellow  Green  Green  Green 
2        Yellow  Green   Green  Green  Green 
3        Red     Red     Red    Yellow Green"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```